# Laravel 4: Where Clause in Model or in Controller?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
users
  - id
  - username

kids
 - id
 - user_id

groups
 - id

group_user
 - id
 - group_id
 - user_id

sits
 - id
 - user_id
```

They of course have addl fields, but it's just extraneous info.

My User model contains:

```
public function kids()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Kid');
}

public function sits()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Sit');
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Group')->withPivot('status');
}
```

My UserController@show method looks like this:

```
public function show($user)
{
    $user = User::find($user)->load('kids', 'groups', 'sits');
    return $user;
}
```

So, when I hit `/user/show/1` I get the JSON I expect.

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "username": "somename",
  "email": "somename@example.com",
  "kids": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "user_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "user_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "user_id": "1"
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Group Name",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": "1",
        "group_id": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "sits": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "user_id": "1",
      "start": "2014-01-16 00:00:31",
      "end": "2014-01-16 00:00:31",
      "sitter_id": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

But my question is what is the "Laravel Way" to add another object to this response that is filtered? Let's say I wanted to return `sits` but also `upcomingSits` where it was filtered by a certain "start" date or where "sitter_id"=0.

Where is the proper MVC approach for that sort of logic and how would I use Laravel to return it in this response?

Comment: Just reading about the best approach to this myself: [Some tips for laravel newbies](http://laravel.io/topic/18/some-tips-for-laravel-newbies) (specifically the section entitled `Your ORM is not your model`)

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Yeah, the ORM is not your model has some good thoughts in it. But, it's still unclear to me. I could just perform the logic within my js template because I have everything I need; it just seems like there's probably a much better way.

Comment: Using a Repository interface instead of tying the controller direct the ORM seems to be popular with a few people in the Laravel community - can help with testing, and allows an easier swapping out of the persistence infrastructure at a later date if you want - there is a reasonably simple intro to this approach as part of this testing tutorial - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/testing-laravel-controllers/ - so the answer could be that the 'where' clause doesn't go in the model or the controller - depends on size and complexity of your app :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$user = User::with('kids', 'groups', 'sits')->find($user_id)->toArray();
$sits = Sit::where(.....)->get()->toArray(); 

return Response::json(array(
    'user' => $user,
    'sits' => $sits
));
```